# Do not see `/var/jenkins_home/workspace` directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have started a jenkins container like so:

```
docker run -u $(id -u) -dit -p 49001:8080 -v "$(pwd)/jenkins_home":/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

This basically starts and container and I am able to run my pipelines. I created a very simple pipeline like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  
  stages {
     stage('Hello') {
       steps {
          input message: 'Do you want to proceed', ok: 'Yes'
       }
     }
  }
}
```

When I run the pipeline I see the following console output for this pipeline:

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/first_pipeline
...
Do you wnat to proceed
Yes or Abort
```

I have let the pipeline hang there but not supplying the input and went into check the workspace directory inside docker container and I do not see any subdirectory `workspace` inside `/var/jenkins_home`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Possibly because the "Running on ..." is an initialization message and nothing in the pipeline required a workspace yet.

Comment: @IanW you are correct, that was the reason. Since my pipeline did not have any artifacts generated to be placed in those directories so the actual workspace was not created. I changed the pipeline and I can see the content. I have pasted the updated pipeline as shown in my response.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue was exactly what `@Ian W` mentioned in comment above. If I update the pipeline to actually create files then I can see the workspace being created. Here is the updated pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                writeFile(file: "test.txt", text: "Main workspace")
                dir(pwd(tmp: true)) {
                    writeFile(file: "test.txt", text: "Temporary workspace")
                }
                input message: 'Do you want to proceed', ok: 'Yes'
                echo "Test completed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```